# Is there a limit of nested documents per field?

Tags: elasticsearch, nested

In my elasticsearch mapping i have a nested field, as shown in code. Is there a limit for the quantity of objects that I can save for 'uuid' fields?

```
'uuids' => [
    'type' => 'nested',
    'properties' => [
        'uuid' => [
            'type' => 'keyword'
        ]
    ]
]
```

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/mapping.html

Comment: Thx a lot, I took a look at that page tons of times without noticing the default limit of 10.000 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is already answered in the comments to the question, but since that's a link only answer, here is the relevant section:

From [Limits on nested mappings and objects](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html#_limits_on_nested_mappings_and_objects)

> **index.mapping.nested_objects.limit**
>
> The maximum number of nested JSON objects that a single document can contain across all `nested` types. This limit helps to prevent out of memory errors when a document contains too many nested objects. Default is `10000`.